# Доступ к public полям из private методов

Tags: coffeescript

```
class @ChatApp
  # public
  constructor: (config) ->
    @dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(window.location.host + "/websocket")
    bindEvents()

  log: (message) =>
    $('#chat_history').append message

  #private
  bindEvents = ->
    console.log this        # указывает на window
    console.log @dispatcher # undefined
    console.log @log        # undefined
    @dispatcher.bind 'log', @log

  # немного исправляет ситуацию, если написать 
  bindEvents = =>
    console.log this        # заменяется на ChatApp
    console.log @dispatcher # ChatApp.dispatcher = undefined
    console.log @log        # ChatApp.log = undefined
    @dispatcher.bind 'log', @log
```

код выдает ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Comment: проще всего передавать создаваемый объект параметром

Comment: я тоже об этом думал, но это какой то некрасивый вариант

Comment: если посмотрите во что преобразуется ваш код - это единственная возможность оставить функцию приватной. Ну кроме вызова `bind` напрямую в конструкторе

Comment: [вот во что он преобразуется](https://pp.vk.me/c630422/v630422801/2c226/OZkexEQXDoA.jpg)
это с `bindEvents = =>`

Comment: Вот именно: `bindEvents` - это обычная локальная функция, никак не связанная с конструируемым объектом. Следовательно без передачи параметром, либо установки `this` вручную никак нельзя обратиться к создаваемому объекту

Comment: [похоже на грязный хак](https://vk.com/doc270051801_437481552?hash=a25f7de20593356784&dl=9d8eebf1a43ea046be)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39133/discussion-between-bjornmelgaard-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следуя [статье](http://bestmike007.com/blog/2014/11/06/a-note-about-private-class-members-in-coffeescript-slash-javascript/), приватные не статические методы нужно создавать в конструкторе, как в этом примере

```
# CoffeeScript
class Square
    # private static variable
    counter = 0
    # private static method
    countInstance = ->
        counter++; return
    # public static method
    @instanceCount = ->
        counter
    constructor: (side) ->
        countInstance()
        # side is already a private variable, we define a private variable `self` to avoid evil `this`
        self = this
        # private method
        logChange = ->
            console.log "Side is set to #{side}"
        # public methods
        self.setSide = (v) ->
            side = v
            logChange()
        self.area = ->
            side * side
s1 = new Square(2)
console.log s1.area()   # output 4
s2 = new Square(3)
console.log s2.area()   # output 9
s2.setSide 4            # output Side is set to 4
console.log s2.area()   # output 16
console.log Square.instanceCount() # output 2
```

но это не подходит для моего проекта, по-этому я делаю метод `bindEvents` открытым